# Load string from .txt and display HTML-file in a webBrowser in VisualStudio

Tags: c#, html, filestream

I am working in Visual Studio 2017 and I got a folder containing HTML-files, which I want to display in a webBrowser-Element.

I tried different methods, but always get a NULL-exception and want to find a method to load a string (containing a filepath to the HTML) from a .txt-file and navigate my webBrowser-element to this filepath.

```
try
        {
            //Pass the file path and file name to the StreamReader constructor
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:/install/Win10-Tipps/link.txt");

            line = sr.ReadLine();

            //Continue to read until you reach end of file
            while (line != null)
            {
                //write the lie to console window
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                //Read the next line
                line = sr.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                Uri link = new Uri(line);
                Console.WriteLine(link);
                webBrowser1.Navigate(link);


            }

            //close the file
            sr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception");
        }
```

It prints "file://C:/Install/Win10-Tipps/TippsHTML/TippSchnellePcSperre.html" which is the correct filepath, but also prints ""System.ArgumentNullException" in System.dll"

Comment: add code of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I got your intentions right:
I got a Textfile with the name "pathToWebsite.txt" containing the path to an html file (in my case C:\test.html).

Reading the path to the html is pretty straight forward:

```
        string url = null;

        using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\pathToWebsite.txt"))
        {
            //If the textfiles only contains one url in the first line.
            url = reader.ReadLine();
        }
```

Then I can simply tell my webBrowser to Navigate to that path:

```
if(url != null)
{
    //Maybe a check to make sure url is a valid path to a html page.
    webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you! But why is the string in the correct format now, and why hasn't it been before?

Comment: After seeing you code above, the only thing I see is that you got the url with the first ReadLine. You then Write it to the console and do another readline without checking for null. Then it crashes, because the argument for new Url can not be null.

Comment: So I was only missing the handler for the case null, thanks for your help.